# My if statement in spritekit (swift isn't working). I'm trying to increase the number of obstacles as the score gets higher

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm creating a game in Spritekit where a player has to collect coins. While collecting them, they have to avoid bombs. Basically, I want to increase the number of bombs that appear as the score gets higher... so I used an if statement - but it isn't working. The number of bombs that appear tends to stay the same:

```
 if self.score >= 0 && self.score < 20 {

        bombTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.createBomb()
        })

    } else if self.score >= 20 && self.score < 35 {

        bombTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.createBomb()
        })

    } else if self.score >= 35 && self.score < 50 {

        bombTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.createBomb()
        })

    } else if self.score >= 50 && self.score < 150 {

        bombTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.createBomb()
        })

    }
```

Comment: What are you doing with the bombTimer? Have you checked to see that createBomb works properly? Or that as the score increases, the code falls into different if clauses?

Comment: bombTimer is my variable of type Timer (var bombTimer : Timer?). I have checked that 'createBomb' works properly. It's just that the number of bombs that appear is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing code inside of a SKScene class I like to use SKActions rather than NSTimers since the actions will pause when the scene is paused.

Paste this function inside your scene class somewhere.
Using a switch statement is nicer to use when working with a buttload of conditions

```
func getBombInterval() -> Double? {
    switch true {
    case score >= 0 && score < 20: return 4
    case score < 35: return 3
    case score < 50: return 2
    case score < 150: return 1
    default: return nil
    }
}
```

Then replace the code you posted above with this:

```
guard let interval = getBombInterval() else { print("Score is less than 0") ; return }
    let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: interval)
    run(waitAction, completion: { self.createBomb() } )
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but after some time, the bombs stop appearing. Thanks for your help, though.